# Adjusting a figure vertically on a beamer template

Tags: beamer, subfloats

I am trying to adjust a figure containing 2 images of different sizes. Is there a way to adjust the left image on the centerline of the template ? I have tried to use the command `\centerline` but without any result...

[image]

```
\documentclass[french]{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand\WWider[2][2em]{%
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth+#1\relax}
  \raggedright#2
  \end{minipage}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Etat de l'art}
\begin{frame}{Les précèdents travaux}
 \WWider[2em]{
\begin{figure}    
    \subfloat[{\scriptsize J.Lister, J.Neufeld, JFM (2018)} ] {{\includegraphics[height = 0.35 \textheight,width=0.45 \linewidth ]{pic/ListerExperiment.png} }}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[{\scriptsize En bleu, les résultats expérimentaux. En rouge, le modèle (PF). En vert, le modèle (VT)}] {{\includegraphics[width=0.45 \linewidth]{pic/BerhanuExperiment.png} }}%
    \end{figure}
    }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your example is not compiling: `\usepackage{graphicx}` is missing and you should use place holder images like `example-image`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use beamer columns to vertically centre the images including their captions.

This will avoid your `\WWider` workarounds to cause more problems. Beamer columns automatically decrease the width of the margins.

```
\documentclass[french]{beamer}

\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}

\subsection{Etat de l'art}
\begin{frame}{Les précèdents travaux}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{figure}    
    \subfloat[{\scriptsize J.Lister, J.Neufeld, JFM (2018)} ] {{\includegraphics[height = 0.15 \textheight,width=\linewidth ]{example-image} }}%
    \end{figure}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{figure}
\phantomsubcaption
\subfloat[{\scriptsize En bleu, les résultats expérimentaux. En rouge, le modèle (PF). En vert, le modèle (VT)}] {{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} }}%
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Load [adjustbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) after [graphicx](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) with `[export]` and add the option `valign=c` to `\includegraphics` if you want only images themselves to be aligned by their middle points (excluding sub-caption).

[image]

However, if you want to align images including their sub-captions, just insert each `\subfloat` into a separate `\parbox`

[image]

Multi-lined sub-captions can also be changed to using hanging format; this is set by `\captionsetup` in case you would prefer that.

---

Code for the first example

```latex
\documentclass[french]{beamer}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup{format=hang}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Etat de l'art}
\begin{frame}{Les précèdents travaux}
  \begin{figure}
    \subfloat[\scriptsize J.Lister, J.Neufeld, JFM (2018)]%
      {\includegraphics[
        height=0.25\textheight,
        width=0.45\linewidth,
        valign=c,
      ]{example-image}}%
    \hfill%
    \subfloat[\scriptsize En bleu, les résultats expérimentaux. En rouge, le modèle (PF). En vert, le modèle (VT)]%
      {\includegraphics[
        width=0.45\linewidth,
        valign=c,
      ]{example-image}}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

A snippet for `figure` environment for the second example (the rest of the code is the same)

```latex
  \begin{figure}
    \parbox{0.45\linewidth}{%
      \subfloat[\scriptsize J.Lister, J.Neufeld, JFM (2018)]%
        {\includegraphics[
        height=0.25\textheight,
        width=\linewidth,
      ]{example-image}}
    }%
    \hfill%
    \parbox{0.45\linewidth}{%
      \subfloat[\scriptsize En bleu, les résultats expérimentaux. En rouge, le modèle (PF). En vert, le modèle (VT)]%
        {\includegraphics[
        width=\linewidth,
      ]{example-image}}}
  \end{figure}
```

Comment: No need for `\usepackage{graphicx}`, beamer automatically loads it

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you for pointing at this.

Comment: You're welcome!